# React native expo web page refresh from chrome browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

ima having a react native web app and when i refresh the page from browser, it navigates to my apps homepage. is there any way that  could fix that issue. it happens with all my pages. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to explain more in your question and to share code.

Also, are you making a react-native web app? This of course is possible, but it's quite rare. Usually React is used for web and React-Native for mobile.